# Install East Asian Language Pack on target system

Tags: c#, .net, localization, windows-xp

There are a few posts which explain how to detect if a target computer has the East Asian Language pack installed on XP. That is all well and good, but if I find that the language is not installed I would like to have my installation program install the languages without intervention from the user.

Is this possible?

I am targeting XP systems SP2.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am writing in C#. Obviously I can only use .NET 4.0 and lower since it is targeting XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your application install it.

That is a system component, and would have to insert the Windows XP install CD/DVD.
It does not exist stand-alone, and you are not allowed to redistribute it even if you can extract if somehow from the original install disk.

You might also install a Language pack
(http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=xp).

But that also contains UI localization (which you don't need).
And as a user (or as an admin) I would hate an application that installs system stuff.
Just detect, and if not there, open a web page with instructions, all the necessary links, etc.
That's what everybody does.
And the situation should be pretty rare anyway. If I want Japanese (for instance), your application is not the first one, I already have Japanese support installed (and I have XP installed for many-many years :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mihai...Our system Admins had asked me to build it into the installer since we have the systems we are deploying to locked down. They all had the language files on the C drive already, just had to use the silent installer to get windows to install it. A bit of scripting did the trick.